# Changing the world origin in C++ SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I've recently gotten into SFML and as an exercise to get more comfortable (and have fun), I started translating some Coding Challenges done by Daniel Shiffman on his Youtube channel, The Coding Train. Upon attempting to translate a star field effect in SFML, I started searching for the right function in SFML that would change the world origin from the top-left of the screen to the center. The closest thing I found to this was the setOrigin function, but that only works for sprites and not the whole window/screen. If you didn't understand my description of this function, it would be the equivalent of the translate(x, y) function in Processing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SFML uses `sf::View` to control what part of the condinate system is displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sf::View`
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php

Here is a small implementation example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(300, 300), "");
    sf::Vector2u size = window.getSize();
    sf::View view(sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Vector2f(size.x, size.y));
    window.setView(view);

    sf::CircleShape cir(10);
    cir.setOrigin(10, 10);

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
    
        window.clear();
        window.draw(cir);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After you made the circle, you set its origin to 10, 10. Why is that?

Comment: @Laith71 The circle is placed at the point (0, 0), but it is still not in the center of the window, because the origin of the circle is still left-top point

Comment: Oh ok. So does that mean I will have to change the origin of every shape/sprite I make? Thanks.

Comment: In your task (star field effect), there is no reason for the origin of each element.

Comment: So rather than changing the origin of each element, I should use the setCenter() function to the middle of the window?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `setCenter()` once or, as in the example, pass to the constructor `sf::View` two elements where the first will be
`const Vector2f &center`, and the second window size `const Vector2f &size`